# I am having trouble with doing an action on my second form that will change something in my first form

Tags: vb.net, sharpdevelop

I have tried finding an answer for a couple of hours now on reddit and google in general, but I could not find anything. I only have been doing vb programming for a few months (during school), so this might be a really easy question to answer. Also, english is my second language, so if I said anything in an unreadable way, let me know and I will do my best to rephrase it. Here it is:

I have 2 forms: one is MainForm, the second is Form1.

What I want forms to do? Open Form1 with a button on MainForm (already did this, but I couldn't figure out how to do the next steps that follow this one). Then, the user will click on a picturebox in Form1. After being clicked, this same image will appear in another picturebox already in MainForm.

So let's say in Form1 there are 2 pictureboxes: number1 and number2. How do I make it so that if the user clicks number1 in Form1, the picturebox of my choice in MainForm shows the picture number1?

I have tried doing this with labels (transfering text form a textbox in form1 to a textbox in MainForm, but I got an error that says:

'Name.MainForm.Label5' is not accessible in this context, because it is 'Private'. (BC30390)

When I checked, the class was public. Some people online said that the module needs to be public, but it's not in a module, it's in a class.

TL;DR: How do I make one form to be able to interact with the other if it says that the other is private (but  the class of this other isn't). I basically need to do the game MasterMind, but this particular thing blocks me from advancing any further.

Comment: I suggest posting a code sample.

Comment: Use a common event handler for the `Click()` event of all pictureboxes in Form1. Then: `MainForm.PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Image`.

Comment: Ok, I tried both of these options and some programmers tried helping me, but what they say is that sharpdevelop is the program causing trouble apparently. I keep on getting error BC30390 when I do mainform.picturebox1.image

Comment: The default access modifier of controls in `SharpDevelop` is `Private` instead of `Friend`. Just change that. Or keep it `Private` and expose a Public method in `MainForm` with a parameter that lets you pass an `Image` as argument. You should probably use this second option. Or let MainForm subscribe to the PictureBoxes Click() event. Or make Form1 expose a custom public event that notifies the subscribers when a different Image has been chosen. You can pass the new Image reference as part of the custom EventArgs. Many options available.